# Can't pass converted array from query using whereIn

Tags: laravel, controller

I can't pass the first query collection converting it to array. Here is my controller

```
$memberfilters = MemberProfile::join('membership_histories', 'membership_histories.profile_id', '=','member_profiles.id')
        ->select('member_profiles.id','member_profiles.last_name','member_profiles.first_name','member_profiles.middle_name','member_profiles.name_ext','member_profiles.birthday','member_profiles.encoded_by')            
        ->addSelect(DB::raw('membership_histories.profile_id, membership_histories.log_reason, max(membership_histories.effective_date) as date, membership_histories.membership_type, membership_histories.country_name, membership_histories.sub_region_name'))       
        ->orderBy('member_profiles.last_name','ASC')
        ->where('membership_histories.country_name', 'Philippines')         
        ->groupBy('membership_histories.profile_id')    
        ->orderBy('date', 'desc')   
        ->get();

    $members = MemberProfile::join('membership_histories', 'membership_histories.profile_id', '=','member_profiles.id')
        ->whereIn('member_profiles.id', $memberfilters->toArray())
        ->get();
```

I will be applying more where method on the second query $members, that's why I had to pass it to there using whereIn. With this logic, I get no results '0' in my blade view

---

@Alexey Mezenin
When I use `->whereIn('member_profiles.id', $memberfilters->pluck('id'))`, I get this error

> ErrorException in ComputeAge.php line 13:
>   Trying to get property of non-object

This is my ComputeAge.php

```
namespace App\Library;
use App\MemberProfile;
use DateTime;

class ComputeAge
{
// Compute age based on given birthday.
public static function show($id) 
{
    $from = new DateTime(MemberProfile::find($id)->birthday);
    $to   = new DateTime('today');
    $age = $from->diff($to)->y;

    return $age;
}
}
```

Comment: uh.. well.. try to `var_dump` (or even better `dd`) your `$memberfilters`... it feels like, that variable not only contains id..

Comment: Hi @BagusTesa how do I write that again in the controller? where do I add dd

Comment: Hi @RodneyZanoria, sorry for the late answer, it seems @AlexeyMezenin already pointed you to the right direction directly. actually, i want to ascertain the query result after you `->get()` the `MemberProfile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your first issue with `pluck()` like Alexey answered. For your age computing issue. You can make use of carbon to do this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Library;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\MemberProfile;

class ComputeAge
{
    public static function show($id)
    {
        $user = MemberProfile::findOrFail($id);
        $age = $user->birthday->diffInYears(Carbon::now(), false);
        return $age;
    }
}
```

If your birthday field isn't an instance of carbon then do this.

```
$age = Carbon::parse($user->birthday)->diffInYears(Carbon::now(), false);
```

If you don't need negative values for birthday values in the future then you can just call `diffInYears()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pluck()`, for example:

```
->whereIn('member_profiles.id', $memberfilters->pluck('id')) // Or member_profiles.id instead of id
```

Comment: This worked, but I had to comment out a line in my controller because it gave me this error, "ErrorException in ComputeAge.php line 13: Trying to get property of non-object". ComputeAge.php is one of my files to get age. I've updated it's content above for you to check if I got that file right

Comment: @RodneyZanoria if error is here `MemberProfile::find($id)` this simply means there is no profile with ID = $id in DB.

Comment: The error was found in ComputeAge.php file since it is saying it is a non-object. Do you know how I can work around that. I pasted my ComputeAge.php above

Comment: @RodneyZanoria you should check if the record exists in DB, for example: `$profile = MemberProfile::find($id); if (!is_null($profile)) { $from = new DateTime($profile); ... } else { return ...}`

Comment: I apologize but the public function I used for my controller in these set of logic is actually request. I am not looking for a particular ID in my database, but generating a report from a request

Comment: cast those date fields as date so you can readily use Carbon stuff.